# Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object ' Worksheet' failed - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The below code works perfectly when I run it manually, but when I call it in a change event I get Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object 'Worksheet failed.

I am just pasting some row data in a sheet and need this code to "fix" some data which would be otherwise hard to read:

```
Sub PortfolioFixer()
Dim ws As Worksheet, dataLastRow As Long, Cell As Range, MyCov As Range, MyRng As Range, MyID As Range, MyCurrent As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Portfolio")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
dataLastRow = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRng = ws.Range("F2:F" & dataLastRow)
Set MyID = ws.Range("B2:B" & dataLastRow)
Set MyCurrent = ws.Range("G2:G" & dataLastRow)
'   Loop through column B
For Each Cell In MyID
Cell.NumberFormat = "General"
Next Cell
'   Loop through column G
For Each Cell In MyCurrent
Cell.NumberFormat = "[$$-409]#,##0"
Next Cell
'   Loop through column F
For Each Cell In MyRng
If Cell = "" And Cell.Offset(0, 1) = 0 And (Cell.Offset(0, -2) = "BML Rate" Or Cell.Offset(0, -2) = "Availability") Then
            Cell = "Shopped"
ElseIf Cell = "" And Cell.Offset(0, 1) > 0 And (Cell.Offset(0, -2) = "BML Rate" Or Cell.Offset(0, -2) = "BML Availability") Then
            Cell = "Action Required"
ElseIf Cell >= 0 And (Cell.Offset(0, -2) = "BML Rate" Or Cell.Offset(0, -2) = "BML Availability") Then
Cell.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
 Else
End If
Next Cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It seems that everything has been referenced but Excel says no and cannot figure out why.

Comment: Have you set `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the change event? Else writing into the sheet will recursively trigger another change event

Comment: Great, that was missing, thank you